# Copy partial rows from one sheet to another and then sort the results

Tags: vba, excel

Kind of new to VBA so appreciate any assistance, I am trying to copy data from rows in one worksheet to another, remove the blank lines and sort the data in column "V" from largest to smallest. The copy and paste is fine, but when I sort it is leaving the blank rows at the top of the "Winning" sheet and the sorted data at the bottom.

Before the Sort:

[image]

```
Sub CreateListOfTeams()

'Copy the data
Sheets("Team").Range("AB4:AW301").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Winning").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A2").Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:V" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("V1:V" & lastrow), _
order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

After Sort with above code:

[image]

Comment: where in your code are you removing the blank rows ? since you are not, when filtering you are getting the blank rows at the top

Comment: I was expecting the sort to place the blank rows to the bottom of the sort leaving the data at the top .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: it's better if you stay away from using `Activate` Sheets("Winning") and later on `Select` the range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateListOfTeams()

'Copy data
Sheets("Team").Range("AB4:AW301").Copy

With Sheets("Winning")
    .Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' clear all blank rows
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & i & ":V" & i)) = 0 Then .Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' find last row after removal of blank rows
    Set Rng = .Range("A1:V" & LastRow) ' set the filter range
    Rng.Sort key1:=.Range("V1:V" & LastRow), _
            order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Shai, the data is Team is created through formulas, it is looking at a list taking teams of 3, then it takes the highest 2 of 3 scores on each hole and gives a total for the team there is an image of the full data here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2VPa.png when I try the code you have provided it says that "No Cells were found"

Comment: Thank you @ShaiRado